# Using \maketitle with custom title page

Tags: titles

I have created a custom title page format within the `titlepage` environment. I'd like to put that in a class or package, and be able to use that format in every document by simply specifying the `\title` and `\author` and calling the `\maketitle` command at the beginning of the document. How could I do it?

Comment: You don't need to make a new class or package just for this. You can redefine the `\maketitle` command.

Comment: `\renewcommand{\maketitle}{\begin{titlepage}...\end{titlepage}}` using \@title and \@author.  This is actually how \maketitle is defined for standard document classses, only the ... part changes.

Comment: The `titling` package might be helpful for that.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-customize-my-titlepage and https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation#A_title_to_be_re-used_multiple_times

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\renewcommand` and `\@title` and `\@author` (as [John Kormylo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/34505/john-kormylo) [pointed out](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/481118/using-maketitle-with-custom-title-page#comment1215862_481118)). This is one way to do it (you can customize `titlepage` to anything you want):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
    \begin{titlepage}
    \topskip0pt
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[
            text width=\textwidth-2cm,
            align=left,
            font=\fontsize{40}{40}\selectfont\scshape,
            inner xsep=.5cm
        ] (x) {\@title};
        \draw (x.north west) node[
            draw,
            above right=2cm and 0pt,
            font=\huge,
            inner sep=.2cm
        ] (y) {\textit{\bfseries By} \textsc{\@author}};
        \draw (y.south west)--($(x.south west)+(0,-2)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \end{titlepage}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\author{My name}
\title{Lorem Lipsum}

\maketitle

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]